# Is observer pattern unidirectional or bidirectional data flow

Tags: javascript

I intend to use observer pattern to update views automatically once value of model has been changed. It's obvious that a model is observable (subject) and DOM elements are observers that are staring at model for any changes so that they can update themselves.

But do you think it is still unidirectional data flow if I have a button which is observing model value and on click modify model value

Comment: So observer pattern is unidirectional and my use case is bidirectional, isn't it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **observer pattern is unidirectional**, but your **use case is bidirectional**, while it's extending the observer pattern implementation.

---

The observer pattern defines, that the subject object will notify the observer if it's updated and the observer will implement an notify() function accordingly.

What you describe isn't part of that pattern. You can implement it and if data flows it would be bidirectional. But it is not part of the pattern definition.

Comment: pseudo code is something like this: button itself is an observer, button label is staring at model value, button click will change model value and invoke notify all observers (including button itself because it is an observer) so it's observer pattern

Comment: Like @joh said, the side-effect is not part of the pattern. That's something which your use case does. Observer pattern only addresses event propagation in one direction.

Comment: So observer pattern is unidirectional and my use case is bidirectional, isn't it ?

Comment: @johannesp: please edit your answer so I can accept it as straight-to-the-point answer, something like "Observer pattern is unidirectional but your use case is bidirectional" since I don't see you mentioned Observer pattern is unidirectional or bidirectional pattern